# Regex: keep everything in <profession></profession> tags

Tags: xml, regex, replace

I have a large XML, looking like this:

```
<gender>M</gender>
<last-name>*</last-name>
<profession>2165dda2-dc59-41af-acb5-06d8914c4841</profession>
<first-name>*</first-name>
<mail-confirmation>1</mail-confirmation>
<fax-confirmation>1</fax-confirmation>
```

I only want to keep the  tags. I found a way to search IN the tag, like this:

```
<profession[^>]*>([^<]*?)</profession>
```

but how do I search everything outside of it? I tried to just flip it, like:

```
</profession[^>]*>([^<]*?)<profession>
```

or

```
</profession>([^<]*?)<profession[^>]*>
```

but that won't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Just get the data _in_ those tags? Only the data outside? Just strip out these tags?

Comment: Exactly; I only want the data inside the profession tag. The rest has to go.

Comment: "How do I use a regex to parse XML/HTML" has been asked countless times here

Comment: are you trying to remove elements named "profession"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly you can't parse XML with a regex.

Quick and dirty solution with sed is to grep the lines with profession then replace "profession"
and "/profession" with ""  (markup is stripping the < > )

Comment: A quick and simple grep, that I didn't think of that!

Comment: You have to be careful if line endings can appear inside the tag

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML. Use an XML parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => \*DATA)
    or die "Cannot read from \\*DATA\n";

while ( $reader->read ) {
    print $reader->readInnerXml if $reader->localName eq 'profession';
}

$reader->finish;
print $reader->document->toString(1);

__DATA__
<person>
<gender>M</gender>
<last-name>*</last-name>
<profession>2165dda2-dc59-41af-acb5-06d8914c4841</profession>
<first-name>*</first-name>
<mail-confirmation>1</mail-confirmation>
<fax-confirmation>1</fax-confirmation>
</person>
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t
2165dda2-dc59-41af-acb5-06d8914c4841
```

See [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::LibXML::Reader).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using XSL to select the values. For example, creating a comma-separated list of professions from your XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <xsl:for-each select="person">
          <xsl:value-of select="profession" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notepad++ has an XML plugin that will run XSL against open files.
(Plugins > XML Tools > XSL Transformation)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
# Perl
$xml =~ s/^<profession>.*<\/profession>$/<profession><\/profession>/m;
```

Just make sure to use the multiline modifier.

Comment: I'm not really using perl. I'm stuck with notepad++'s regex capabilities. Or sed.

Comment: @skerit You do not have a programming question then, do you?

Comment: I have a question about a certain regular expression, it's the same thing as asking something about a specific SQL query.

Comment: Oops, I just realized you want the data OUTSIDE the profession tags gone. Well, Sinan Ünür's example is really good but Perl. Actually it's quite easy, like $xml =~ /<profession>(.*?)<\/profession>/sg but I'm not sure about the regex capabilities of Notepad++. Sorry for the misunderstanding.