# How to read value of a node in Perl libXML::Reader

Tags: perl, libxml2

My XML looks like this-

```
<info>
<name>NameGoesHere</name>
<age>99</age>
</info>
```

Using XML::LibXML::Reader, I would like to print the age.

I read the documentation from [here](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/XML-LibXML/XML/LibXML/Reader.html#value), and I am looking for an example. I am able to use `$reader->nextElement('info')` and then print `innerXML` but not able to figure out how do I print only age and not the whole `innerxml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `localName`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => \*DATA)
    or die "Cannot read from \\*DATA\n";

while ( $reader->read ) {
    print $reader->readInnerXml if $reader->localName eq 'age';
}

$reader->finish;

__DATA__
<info>
<name>NameGoesHere</name>
<age>99</age>
</info>
```

Mostly from [Regex: keep everything in <profession></profession> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372532/regex-keep-everything-in-profession-profession-tags/2372677#2372677)

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if someone can suggest any other alternative too. I don't like "filtering" using if statement - it will be more elegant if I can directly access the value

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML::Reader qw(
   XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT
   XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT
   XML_READER_TYPE_TEXT
);

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => \*DATA);

my $in_age = 0;
my $age;
while ($reader->read()) {
   if ($reader->nodeType() == XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT && $reader->name() eq 'age') {
      $age = '' if !$in_age;
      ++$in_age;
   }
   elsif ($reader->nodeType() == XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT && $reader->name() eq 'age') {
      --$in_age;
      say $age if !$in_age;
   }
   elsif ($in_age && $reader->nodeType() == XML_READER_TYPE_TEXT) {
      $age .= $reader->value();
   }
}

__DATA__
<info>
<name>NameGoesHere</name>
<age>99</age>
</info>
```